# Ubuntu SDK - Custom executable

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sdk, qml

I have a problem with Ubuntu SDK. I try to run project (qml and c++) but I get pop up window with message "Could not find the executable" and some settings (command, arguments, working directory)

[image]

How should I run it?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is really built than you will able to get name of executable. You can get it from compilation log (see what is written after *-o* option in last command) or you can look to build directory with your favorite file manager.

N.B. There is concept of shadow building. If it is enabled final executable will not be stored in source directory. So, you need to disable it, rebuild application, go to sources directory, find new files which have *executable* flag and write it's name to dialog above.

P.S. Don't paste screenshots to SO, it is a bad practice.